# Lambda does not wait for function call completion

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am coding a Lambda that should utilize the [Snowflake NodeJS connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/node-js/nodejs-driver-connect).

My code is:

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import * as snowflake from "snowflake-sdk";

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {

    console.log("JUST WAVING");

    const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
        account: "sfdgfdg",
        username: "user",
        password: "password",
        application: "application"
      });

    console.log(connection);

    // Try to connect to Snowflake, and check whether the connection was successful.
    connection.connect( 
        function(err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
                } 
            else {
                console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
                }
        }
    );
    
    return event;

};
```

I expected this code to return an error as the connection settings are clearly rubbish.

However it prints `JUST WAVING` and shows the functions on the connection coming from the `console.log(connection)` log. After that it exits without anything else.

I am assuming it is not waiting for the response that should come from `connection.connect()`. Am I correct, and how would I solve this?

**Update:**
Using the wise words of @Gary Archer I managed to move a bit in the right direction I believe. The code now is:

```
const asyncConnect = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.connect((err, conn) => {
        if (err) {reject(err);} 
        else {resolve(conn);}
    })
}); 

const conn = await asyncConnect;
```

This does seem to do something. But it keep running untill my Lambda environment reaches a timeout. I assume I am still missing a return somewhere?

Comment: Is there anything in the cloudwatch logs?

Comment: You can promisify the relevant functions. Example [here](https://pipedream.com/@dylburger/promise-based-api-wrapper-for-snowflake-node-sdk-p_XNMCRn/edit).

Answer (score 1):

The `connection.connect` call uses older style callback syntax. You need to wrap it in a promise and then await it, so that code runs sequentially:

```js
const connection = ...

const asyncConnect = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  connection.connect((err, conn) =>
  
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      return resolve(conn);
    }
  };
};

try {
  const conn = await asyncConnect();
  ...

  // Return success payload
} catch (e: any) {
  // Return failure payload
}
```

In terms of control over returned error responses, return an object with `statusCode` and `body` properties, as in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing/utilities/responseWriter.ts).

Comment: This will not run as `connection.connect()` now is missing arguments it expects.

Comment: Oops - that's what happens when you answer questions on a mobile phone in the pub. See updated answer. You may also need to use `return resolve` ...

Comment: I added an update to my post based in your answer. It seems to do something but it looks like something is still missing there. I am guessing a return or something like it.

Comment: Yeah - try a return resolve - difficult for me to test currently ...